# Is this possible to solve?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Is this possible to solve the length of $AB$ while only knowing that $l_1$ and $l_2$ are two parallel lines?

---

[image]
[Example with geogebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHHht.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: I see similar triangles.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Specifically, include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you. Use descriptive titles, "Is this possible to solve?" doesn't say nothing about the question, it's a completely useless title. If you show some effort writing your question you'll get better feedback on this site, otherwise your question might be closed.

Comment: @player3236 $FD$ does not cross $l_2$ in $A$

Comment: @Raffaele If so, must $DE$ cross $l_2$ in $B$?

Comment: @player3236 I got what you are saying. $FE=39$ is inconsistent with $F,A,D$ or $E,B,D$ aligned or both. I propose to close the peoblem assuming that the length of $FE$ has been (badly) approximated, that $DF$ contains $A$ and $DE$ contains $B$.

Answer (score 3):

Sine law in triangle $ABD$

$\gamma=\beta=37°$ because $l_1\parallel l_2$
$$\frac{AB}{\sin 55^{\circ}}=\frac{25}{\sin (180^{\circ}-55^{\circ}-37^{\circ})}\to AB\approx 20.4913$$

**edit**

The segment $FE$ in the original drawing is a deception. As you can see from the calculation above, $FE$ is not necessary to find $AB$. Furthermore $FE=39$ would make points $D,A,F$ not aligned because $F'E$ is larger than $FE$.

Hope this is clear

---

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: So this is wrong then if FE is 39.34

Comment: how would you solve the length of AB then?

Comment: $AB$ is in the third line. In your drawing $D,A,F$ are not aligned if $FE=39$ @drstuggels

Comment: @Raffaele I'm curious, why did you change the length of FE from 39 (the given length) to 39.34? By doing so you're solving a different question that what OP had asked.

Comment: @uriyaba I'll edit to make it more clear

Comment: Woah. How did you find out about that deception? I feel like now I can't trust any drawing I ever see.

Comment: I used sine law directly on triangle $ABD$ to find $AB$ which is irrational, thus an integer measure for $FE$ was suspect. So I found out that $F,A,D$ are not aligned. @uriyaba

Comment: Brilliant! Should I delete my answer now, since it is wrong?

Comment: @uriyaba ...and lose $20$ points? ... Nahhh!!!!!!!!!!!!  ;)

Comment: Well, if I mean to have any sort of integrity, I should at least address that my answer isn't the right one. Can I edit my answer so it would link to yours?

Comment: @uriyaba In love, war and math everything is allowed ;)

Comment: Excellent! [+1]. Just one little remark: $l_1\parallel l_2\implies \beta=\gamma$ requires $D,B,E$ being aligned. How can you be sure that this is the case? ;)

Comment: @Dr.Mathva You are right: that's why I drew directly $37°$ in my picture :)

Comment: How would you calculate the length of AB then? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This question is tricky!

While it is tempting to use the [Intercept Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem), and calculate $AB$ from the following equation:

$$\frac{DB}{DE}=\frac{AB}{FE}$$

This would yield a wrong answer. [Raffaele's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4016197/728938) explains why very clearly.

Comment: But can we be sure that DE or DF are straight lines?

Comment: @drstuggels Yes; It's most likely defined in the original phrasing of the question, such as that DF and DE are straight lines and the points of intersection with $l_1$ and $l_2$ are noted as A, B, F and E.

Comment: Well let's asume that they aren't straight lines, how could that be proved?

Comment: The info in my question is all the info there is. Similar phrasing and all.

Comment: If it was as you say then it should be $FE\approx 39.3433$

Comment: This answer is wrong. Listen to @Raffaele.

Comment: I stand corrected, thank you @Raffaele!